# Java: Generate random file name for the Robot screencapture

Tags: java

Currently, I am trying to create a screencapture using the Robot function. For now I can already screenshot using a button and save it in a form of image. Now I want to do the same but i want to generate different file name such as screenshot1.png, screenshot2.png. Can i know how to randomly generate the numbers using the for loop.

This is my current Java working code:

```
private void jbtnCaptureActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        try {
            Rectangle screenRect = new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize());
            Robot ro = new Robot();
            BufferedImage capture = ro.createScreenCapture(screenRect);
            File f;
            f = new File("myimage1.jpg");                         
            ImageIO.write(capture, "jpg", f);
            System.out.println("Success");



        } catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println("Unable to capture the screen" + e);
        }

}
```

Can someone help me on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: why do you want it to be "random"?  Random means you cannot tell the sequence of screen capture by the file name, random also mean you may have duplicated file name

Comment: so are there any better ways to do it @AdrianShum? because i need to show multiple images for comapring purposes.

Comment: Can't you just keep a running sequence number in your application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess each screen capture is triggered by some kind of button click right (instead of multiple captures in a loop)?

The most straight-forward way is to keep an integer as running sequence for your filename:

```
private void jbtnCaptureActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    .....
            File f = new File("myimage" + (this.filenameSeq++) + .jpg");
    ......
}
```

---

And, if your capture is not generated extremely frequently (e.g. hundreds of files each second), there is another way you can do to avoid keeping a running sequence.  You can generate your filename based on current time, and check if file exists.  If it exists, keep appending a sequence number until you find a file not exist.  In psuedo-code:

```
String filenameBase = "myImage";
String currentTimestamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyymmddHHMMss").format(now());
File f = new File(filenameBase + currentTimestamp +  ".png");
for (int i = 0; f.exists(); i++) {
    f = new File(filenameBase + currentTimestamp +  "-" + i + ".png");
}
// so here, you will have a filename which is not yet exists in your filessystem
```

Comment: I said it is pseudo-code!  It is just giving you the idea, not aiming for you to copy and paste!

Answer (score 0):

Simply use a pseudo-random generator:

```
Random rnd = new Random();
String filename = "screenshot" + rnd.nextInt() + ".png";
```

Of course, initialize the pseudo-random generator outside the function and keep it from one screenshot to another.

Answer (score 0):

Why not dynamically check for existence of filename[x].jpg , incrementing the number until no file exists with that name..

```
public File getUniqueFile(String name) {
     int i=1;
     File file;
     do {
        file = new File(name + (i++) + ".jpg");
     } while (file.exists());
     return file;
}
```

Comment: didn't notice Adrian had given the same answer